Paho-mqtt cannot re-connect after network down, socket.py exception: socket.gaierror: [Errno -3] Temporary failure in name resolution
I have an MQTT wrapper that works as it should until network connection lost:
from paho.mqtt.client import Client as mqttClient
import paho.mqtt.client as paho
from queue import Queue
import time

class mqtt_instance:
    def __init__(self, client_id, host, port, auth):
        #"mqttClient.CallbackAPIVersion.VERSION1" for paho-mqtt version 2.0.0 otherwise remove it
        self._client_id = client_id
        self._host = host
        self._port = port
        
        self.suppress_exceptions = True
        
        self.connected = False
        self._reconnect = True

        # Just as a placeholder in def
        self.do_nothing = None
        # This list is needed when client re-connects to broker to re-subscribe to topics
        self.topic_list = []
        
    # setup queue to capture messages from topic subscription
        self.q = Queue()

        # instantiate client from paho.mqtt library
        #print('MQTT WRAPPER: Instantiating mqtt client...')
        #self.client = mqttClient(mqttClient.CallbackAPIVersion.VERSION1)
        self.client = mqttClient(client_id=self._client_id, userdata=None, protocol=paho.MQTTv5)

        # Auth
        if auth is not None:
            self._user = auth[0]
            #print('MQTT WRAPPER: user:', self._user)
            self._pass = auth[1]
            #print('MQTT WRAPPER: pass:', self._pass)
            # enable TLS for secure connection
            self.client.tls_set(tls_version=paho.ssl.PROTOCOL_TLS)
            # set username and password
            self.client.username_pw_set(self._user, self._pass)

        # register callbacks
        #print('MQTT WRAPPER: registering callbacks...')
        self.client.on_connect = self._on_connect
        self.client.on_disconnect = self._on_disconnect
        self.client.on_subscribe = self._on_subscribe
        self.client.on_publish = self._on_publish
        self.client.on_unsubscribe = self._on_unsubscribe
        self.client.on_message = self._on_message

    def _on_connect(self, client, userdata, flags, rc, properties=None):
        print('MQTT WRAPPER: connected')
        #print('MQTT WRAPPER: rc = {0}'.format(rc))

        if rc == 0:
            #print('MQTT WRAPPER: MQTT connection established...')
            self.do_nothing = None
        else:
            #print('MQTT WRAPPER: MQTT connection failed...')
            self.do_nothing = None

        self.connected = True

        for topic in self.topic_list:
            self.client.subscribe(topic)

    def _on_reconnect(self):
        print('MQTT WRAPPER: reconected')
        self.connected = True

    def _on_disconnect(self, client, userdata, rc, properties=None):
        #print('MQTT WRAPPER: on disconnect')
        self.connected = False
        print('MQTT WRAPPER: disconnected!')
        
        self.client.reconnect()

    def begin(self):
        # connect the client to the mqtt broker
        while not self.check_internet_connection:
            time.sleep(30)
        #print('MQTT WRAPPER: establishing connection...')
        self.client.connect(
            host=self._host,
            port=self._port,
            keepalive=60
        )
        self.client.loop_start()

After network connection is lost socket.py throws exception:
File "/home/pi/venv-ts/lib/python3.12/site-packages/paho/mqtt/client.py", line 3685, in _create_socket_connection
return socket.create_connection(addr, timeout=self._connect_timeout, source_address=source)
       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/socket.py", line 828, in create_connection
for res in getaddrinfo(host, port, 0, SOCK_STREAM):
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/socket.py", line 963, in getaddrinfo
for res in _socket.getaddrinfo(host, port, family, type, proto, flags):
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
socket.gaierror: [Errno -3] Temporary failure in name resolution

I am using paho-mqtt 1.6.1 version.
I have put self.suppress_exceptions = True to prevent paho-mqtt code not to throw exception when network is down. Before I put this line paho-mqtt was failing, but now, socket.py fails.
How to prevent this type of exception?

suppress_exceptions - you would need to call self.client.suppress_exceptions= self.suppress_exceptions for that to apply. Why are you calling reconnect in _on_disconnect? (the library will generally do this for you; however I cannot see a network loop in your code).

Thank you for reply. I have added "self.client.suppress_exceptions= self.suppress_exceptions" after "self.suppress_exceptions = True". "self.client.loop_start()" is under def begin. It was copy/paste error.

As for re-connect in on_disconnect, I was trying to force it to reconnect. Does loop tries to re-connect when connection dropped?

"I have added" - that will not help because self.client is set later on (which will overwrite the earlier change, so you need to move the new line down a bit). "Does loop tries to re-connect " - correct as per the docs "This call also handles reconnecting to the broker". Note: I would recommend updating to the v2 library (it addresses a range of issues and provides a more consistent API).

I get an error:
self.client.suppress_exceptions= self.suppress_exceptions
^^^^^^^^^^^
AttributeError: 'mqtt_instance' object has no attribute 'client'

Sorry - please update your code to match what you are now using. You are already using self.client (e.g. self.client.on_connect = self._on_connect) so I'm guessing the order is still wrong. However if you don't call reconnect in _on_disconnect then the reason for setting suppress_exceptions probably goes away (just ignoring exceptions is not generally a good idea).

Ok. I removed line of code. How do I prevent socket.py exception? I also removed re-connect in _on_disconnect.

If you are not reconnecting in on_disconnect then I would not expect the exception to occur (the library handles it). Note that the error itself indicates that you have a DNS issue (or perhaps the network link is totally down).

When network goes down, I loose connection. MQTT tries to connect using socket.py and then socket.py throws an exception because network is down. I do not know how to catch that exception in code to prevent MQTT to try to connect until network is up again or to "restart" socket.py after exception.

Let us continue this discussion in chat.
